# If MySQL results only one row than it should redirect to detail of the row item

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to fetch data from MySQL. Data is shown in a table showing number of results found (One in each row). In the first column of table, I've provided the link to details page for the row item. I want that if number of results found is only one row than user should be redirected to the details page instead of showing table for results found. How can I do this?

Comment: start with showing some code.

Comment: Use `header('Location: ' . $url_of_details_page);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your connecting to your database:

mysql (not recommended):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
{ header('location: somepage.php'); }
```

mysqli:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
{ header('location: somepage.php'); }
```

PDO:

```
$db = $pdo->query("SELECT ...");
$db->execute();

$result = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(COUNT($result)==1){ header('location: somepage.php'); }
```

For simplicity, I haven't fully done the PDO segment, only how you could count the results and base a redirect from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 1){
  header("Location: your_next_page.php");
  die();
}
```

Comment: -0.5 `mysql_` functions are deprecated.